# Get a horizontal scrollbar in jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, carousel

I am new to jquery and did lot of googling before finally coming to this question.
I am trying to have  [**this**](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/966/jQuery-Horizontal-automatic-Scrollbars-with-mouse)  plugin in a webpage,but this carousel is not responsive.
My prefernce is to have responsive carousel with horizontal scrollbar.
There are lot of carousel but they all have either bullets or thumbnails or numbers for scrolling which i dont want.

- Is there any procedure to have a scrollbar instead of the bullets or
  thumbnails in an existing carousel?
- Is there any good responsive slider plugin in jquery which has horizontal scrollbar included ?
- Can i not convert the quoted link of carousel into a responsive one?
  thankx for any help! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery.horizontal.scroll.css there are some default styles defined, also witdth of carousel.
You can override this styles with your own styles:

```
#horiz_container_outer  {
    width: auto;
}

#scrollbar, #track {
    width: 100%;
}
```

That makes carousel to fit 100% width of the page.

You can also wrap it with div, to control its width easily. See my example http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/XKLEB/

Is it responsive in your definition or you meant something else?

Comment: responsive means that the website should always fit in irrespective of the window size....its should fit in tablets,smartphone,ipad and laptops without creating a horizontal window scroller.For example check this responsive caraousle @ http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider and change ur window size to understand what i meant (:

Comment: its generating horizontal page scroll on reducing the window size,wherein ideally,it should reduce the scrollbar width.